# dropbox configuration

Tags: dropbox

I've dropbox v1.4.17 installed and I want to change the path from (...)/Dropbox to (...)/dropbox.

I think until v1.2 this was done by changing dropbox_path field in the sqlite file ~/.dropbox/config.db. Now, this field is hidden inside the encrypted ~/.dropbox/config.dbx (security reasons (in [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqmqtborOSw)), I guess).

Anyone has a solution to this? I'm thinking about placing my dropbox folder in ~/.local/share/Dropbox and then linking that to the path I want to set.

Answer (score 3):

right click the dropbox tray icon and click **Preferences**, hit the **Advanced**-Tab and change the **Dropbox Location** to the new location.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but its not that easy. That dialog should have been the right way to do it, but when you click "Move..." and select a different directory, it puts a folder called "Dropbox" inside the folder you've selected. What I want is for the dropbox root folder to be named with wathever name I want to give it

Comment: ok i see, i couldn't find anything either, i guess the easiest way is really to place the Dropbox folder to some place and create a link to it with the name of your wish.

Comment: I have installed dropbox, its syncing, but I don't have that icon. How can I launch this?